# Workaround for Drag and Drop SVG elements in Chrome using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, svg, nightwatch.js

**Details:**

```
"chromedriver": "^87.0.7",
"geckodriver": "^1.22.1",
"html-dnd": "^1.2.1",
"nightwatch": "^1.5.1",
```

**Expected**

Drag and drop an SVG element to other SVG element using `Nightwatch` framework in `JavaScript`.

**Actual**

Test passes but no actual movement has occurred.

**Description**
I have tried using the following:

```
browser.moveToElement(locator, dragElement, 1, 1);
browser.mouseButtonDown(0);
browser.moveToElement(locator, dropElement, 1, 1);
browser.mouseButtonUp(0);
```

I noticed moving the mouse while the test was running would allow the drag and drop to work on SVG elements.

Used `html-dnd` and nothing.

```
const dragAndDrop = require('html-dnd').codeForSelectors;

"Drag and Drop": function (browser) {
        browser.url(myurl);
        browser.useXpath();
        browser.execute(dragAndDrop, [svgDragElement, svgDropElement]);
        browser.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
If the code snippet below doesn't work, on the second `moveToElement()` change the pixels in X and y axis

Ok so with a lot of trial and error plus help from fellow Automation engineers I found the solution.

```
browser.moveToElement(locator, dragElement, 1, 1);
browser.mouseButtonDown(0);
browser.moveToElement(locator, dragElement, 1, 1);    // yes, move to your starting 
browser.moveToElement(locator, dropElement, 1, 1);    // element again
browser.mouseButtonUp(0);
```

can't explain this weird behavior but my guess it gets the "focus" on the element which is necessary for the method to work.

**NOTE**
In some cases `browser.pause()` will be necessary between `moveToElement()`